# Calculate output vector in a way that for every element i, output[i] is the product of all values of the input vector other than i

Tags: algorithm

Implement the function, that receives as input a List and returns another List of the same length, so that for every element i result[i] is the product of all values of the input vector except the one at the position i in the input vector.

Examples :

input = {1,2,3}   //output = {6,3,2}

input = {1,2,3,4} //output = {24,12,8,6}

input = {2,0,2,3} // output = {0,12,0,0}

input = {0,2,0,3} // output = {0,0,0,0}

Tried in java, with some edge cases and multiple zero's in input eg: {2,0,2,3}, {0,2,0,0} etc..

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ProductArray {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("This is a debug message");

        List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        input.add(3);
        input.add(2);
        input.add(2);
        input.add(1);
        input.add(1);
        
        ProductArray productArray = new ProductArray();
        List<Integer> results = productArray.arrayProducts(input);
        
        System.out.print(results.toString());
    }

    public List<Integer> arrayProducts(List<Integer> input){
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int arraySize = input != null ? input.size() : 0;
        int itr = 0;
        int totalProduct = 1;
        int zeroCount = 0;
        if(arraySize > 2){          // else empty list returned
            // loop to find totalProduct and zeroCount
            do{
                if(input.get(itr) != 0) {
                    totalProduct *= input.get(itr); 
                } else {
                    ++zeroCount;
                }
                itr++;
            }while(itr < arraySize);
            
            for(Integer element : input){
                if(zeroCount > 1) {
                    result.add(0);
                } else if(zeroCount == 1 ) {
                    if(element == 0) {
                        result.add(totalProduct);
                    } else {
                        result.add(0);
                    }
                } else if(zeroCount == 0 ) {
                    result.add(totalProduct/element);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has multiple duplicates. The typical solution seems to be two prefixes, one from either end. Meet in the middle for each element without it.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you just compute the product of all the elements in `set1`, and then each element `i` in `set2`, will be that product divided by the element `set1[i]`

here is a C++ implementation:

```
void solve(){
    const int input_size = 4;
    int set1[input_size] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int result[input_size];

    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < input_size; ++i) {
        product = product * set1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input_size; ++i) {
        result[i] = product / set1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input_size; ++i) {
        cout << result[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: What if the input set contains one or multiple zero's in it. Like {2,0,2,3} here the output should be {0,12,0,0}.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution in Ruby, heavily annotated to explain the logic.  Several test cases are presented at the bottom.  The overall complexity is `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the input array/list.

```ruby
def products(ary)
  # Pick out the zeros and count - O(ary.size)
  num_zeros = ary.select(&:zero?).size

  # Return an array of all zeros if there's more than 1 zero
  return Array.new(ary.size, 0) if num_zeros > 1

  # Compute the product of all the non-zero values - O(ary.size)
  product = ary.inject(1) { |memo, x| x.zero? ? memo : memo * x }

  # If there are no zeros, create the answer by mapping each value
  # to the product divided by the current value - O(ary.size)
  if num_zeros.zero?
    return ary.map { |x| product / x }
  else
    # Otherwise, all values map to zero except the element whose value
    # is zero, which maps to the product of the non-zeros - O(ary.size)
    return ary.map { |x| x.zero? ? product : 0 }
  end
end

p products [3, 2, 1]        # [2, 3, 6]
p products [-3, -2, -1]     # [2, 3, 6]
p products [-3, 2, -1]      # [-2, 3, -6]
p products [2, 4, 0, 6]     # [0, 0, 48, 0]
p products [2, 0, 4, 6, 0]  # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```